# What is the meaning of the expiration date on a Delta voucher?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, terminology, delta-air-lines, vouchers

My parents were issued vouchers for a specific dollar amount towards future travel on Delta as compensation for volunteering to switch to a different flight in an overbook situation. The vouchers have an expiration date on them of 1 year from when their flight was originally scheduled. My question is what the exact meaning of that 'expiration' date is.

- Is it the date by which they must book travel?
- Is it the date by which they must begin travel?
- Is it the date by which their travel must be complete?
- Or is it something else?

Apparently the voucher itself does not state which of these is the case and I didn't see the answer on a quick search of Delta's website.

Comment: Common sense says, it should be last date to redeem the voucher. That is, the date in which to book.

Comment: @MeNoTalk True, but common sense and airline policy don't always agree. - haha

Comment: reirab, it seems it applies for this case ;)

Comment: @MeNoTalk my common sense would've said it was the date to have made the trip; a few years back a friend of mine lost a long range bus voucher by making the same assumption as yours.

Comment: @Dan, I agree if it was points, but when it is money, then the money can be used to purchase the ticket for once. So logic says it will be treated as in credit cards expiration dates..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Delta](https://www.delta.com/edoc/displayEdocTnC.action?newWindow=Y&TD=IVI0200&source=internal), for eCerts:

> Delta eCerts Credit Voucher must be redeemed and ticket issued by the date above. Extensions are not permitted.

So, the date shown is the last date in which you can issue the ticket, not the date to end the travel.